# How to enable DynamoDBEnableServerSideEncryption in Flutter App using AWS Amplify?

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, aws-amplify, flutter-aws-amplify

I need to enable DynamoDBEnableServerSideEncryption (set to true in the backend folder), but it doesn't let me edit the read-only files. How can I set the parameter to true through the console? Thanks. I have a Flutter application that uses DataStore GraphQL.